# Empathy integration with Gnome3 failed

Tags: gnome3, empathy

I've migrated recently to the new Debian stable, by installing the new system but saving all my data in the `/home` partition. I do this because I don't want the data to be lost between installations, besides, it also saves the configuration of all my applications like Icewaesel bookmarks, Icedove mail accounts. However, I think my old configuration is breaking some features of Gnome3.

For example, it seems like if Empathy weren't integrated with Gnome3 at all. I can't set my status with the user menu and notifications aren't showed when anyone talks to me.

I've tried to remove some folders like `.gnome`, `.gnome2`, `.conf`... to reset the configuration to defaults, but it didn't work. Any idea about what's the problem?

Comment: Gnome 3 ignores gconf, and the .conf folder is used by individual programs to store their own config. The problem is probably that the new Empathy and Gnome 3 just don't behave the way you want.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I didn't know that! but I've used Gnome 3 in the laptop before and just want the PC to behave the same way, that is, notifying me when somebody talks to me.